# How to get the element count matching text in nth column of Span Table

Tags: xpath, robotframework, selenium2library

```
Col1     Col2   Col3    Col4    Col5

  2     XYZ    Andy     Div2    Address2

  3     NNN    Spencer  Div1    Address3

  4     YYY    Krish    Div8    Address4

  5     ABC    Sima     Div1    Address5
```

I have a span table like the one in the above example, and I'm trying to get the count of cells matching text `Div1` in the 4th column (`Col4`). I tried the below code and got an error (invalid xpath locator):

`${RecordCount}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    //td[4][matches(text(),'Div1')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because of the `matches()` function - it is present in XPath 2.0, while all the browsers support only v1.0; thus the error the locator is invalid.

Just change it to `contains()` and it'll work for you:

```
//td[4][contains(text(),'Div1')]
```

Comment: Thanks Todor. matches() function was the issue as you pointed out. Since I need exact match of text, I changed it to     //td[4][text()='Div1'] ,  and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

From the SeleniumLibrary [document](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Matching%20Xpath%20Count) it says that the Get Matching Xpath Count keyword is DEPRECATED in SeleniumLibrary 3.2. Use Get Element Count instead. So you should try to use "Get Element Count" keyword instead. The error you mentioned means your input xpath is wrong. Probably try this `xpath=//td[text()="Div1"]`

Comment: Hi Thanh le -  I started off with xpath=//td[text()="Div1"] only, but that returned me all the cells contained 'Div1' including the cells from other columns. But I need to get the count of Cells with matching text from ONLY the fourth column.

Comment: Then I think you can add the index number as your first post. Probably something like this xpath=//td[4][text()="Div1"]